# Move Part of Row to 2nd Row, and Part of Row to 3rd Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue and I don't know if there's a way out.  I have a large spreadsheet (8000 Rows) that I need to manipulate, where data was put into additional columns when it should've been put into a 2nd and 3rd row instead.  Each entry spans one large row instead of 3 small rows as it should be.  So now I need to create two new rows after each existing row.  Then take data in columns C-F, and move it to the next row (columns A-D).  Then take columns G-H and move that to the 3rd row in the series (Columns A-B).

So an example would be:

Original Data:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8
```

Resulting Data:

```
A1  A2  
A3  A4  A5  A6  
A7  A8

B1  B2  
B3  B4  B5  B6  
B7  B8
```

And so on, until 8000 rows becomes 24000 (or 32000) rows.  Is there any help for me out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this. It may take a bit to complete though. It loops through the 8000 rows inserts 2 rows per row of data, and copies the original data to the appropriate row:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
intRow = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To 8000
    Rows(intRow).Insert
    Cells(intRow, 1) = Cells(intRow - 1, 3)
    Cells(intRow, 2) = Cells(intRow - 1, 4)
    Cells(intRow, 3) = Cells(intRow - 1, 5)
    Cells(intRow, 4) = Cells(intRow - 1, 6)
    Cells(intRow - 1, 3) = ""
    Cells(intRow - 1, 4) = ""
    Cells(intRow - 1, 5) = ""
    Cells(intRow - 1, 6) = ""
    intRow = intRow + 1
    Rows(intRow).Insert
    Cells(intRow, 1) = Cells(intRow - 2, 7)
    Cells(intRow, 2) = Cells(intRow - 2, 8)
    Cells(intRow - 2, 7) = ""
    Cells(intRow - 2, 8) = ""
    intRow = intRow + 2
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```